# Google Apps Script - Crear una biblioteca pública para usar en proyectos ajenos hechos por terceras personas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Por lo que entiendo, la manera más efectiva de poder mantener código en *Google Apps Script* es exportando el mismo como una **biblioteca**.

El problema es que el código que yo desarrollo dentro de mi proyecto, quiero que pueda ejecutarse en proyectos realizados por otros usuarios con otras cuentas de Google.

Veo que en viejas versiones de *Google Apps Script*, esto era posible. Tal y como lo indica [este tutorial](https://sites.google.com/a/mcpher.com/share/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/lib).

Sin embargo, no estaría encontrando la manera moderna de replicar eso mismo en las ultimas versiones.

Por eso mi pregunta es: **¿cómo puedo exportar una biblioteca de *Google Apps Script* para reutilizar mi código en proyectos ajenos?**

Comment: [Aquí tienes toda la documentación actual](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=es-419). Lee también las advertencias y evalúa si lo que te conviene realmente es escribir una biblioteca como dices.

Comment: Gracias. Con esa documentación encontré la solución a mi problema. Con respecto a si me conviene o no usar una biblioteca, lo vi como la opción más conveniente hasta ahora. Ya que mi código debe impactar en archivos hechos por otros usuarios y no veo que sea una buena práctica andar duplicando mi código por cada vez que quiera reutilizarlo. De momento, lo veo como la opción más conveniente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, encontré la parte en la que estaba fallando la importación de mi biblioteca en otros proyectos gracias a la [documentación oficial de las bibliotecas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries?hl=es-419#gain_access_to_a_library).

Allí, en la sección **Obtén acceso a una biblioteca** aclara lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esa es la parte en la que estaba mi falla.

Olvidé dar permisos de vista a mi proyecto de *Google Apps Script*.

Para dar dichos permisos, hay que ir a la sección **Mis proyectos** de la página principal de *Google Apps Script* y tocar los 3 puntos del proyecto al que vamos a autorizar los permisos de vista.

Ahí compartimos el proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego autorizamos el *Acceso general* a "**Cualquier persona con el enlace**":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa manera, otros usuarios van a poder importar nuestra biblioteca en sus proyectos como si fuera de ellos.